# OBIEE expression to filter by previous business date

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, business-intelligence, obiee

I am trying to come up with solution to generate automatic OBIEE 12 report generating automatically for previous business date (e.g. when generating report on Monday, would like to filter data from Friday). I came up with two solutions:

`CURRENT_DATE-1`

Which obviously works well only for reports generated on Tuesday - Saturday.

I came up also with a more sophisticated solution, which returns no results (do not know why):

```
CASE 
   WHEN DayOfWeek(TimestampAdd (SQL_TSI_DAY, -1 , CURRENT_DATE)) = 1 
     THEN TimestampAdd (SQL_TSI_DAY, -3 , CURRENT_DATE)
   WHEN DayOfWeek(TimestampAdd (SQL_TSI_DAY, -1 , CURRENT_DATE)) = 7 
     THEN TimestampAdd (SQL_TSI_DAY, -2 , CURRENT_DATE)
   ELSE TimestampAdd (SQL_TSI_DAY, -1 , CURRENT_DATE)
END
```

When using this expression for filtering date, OBIEE returns info that no data is matched. For the same date proper results are generated with CURRENT_DATE-1 (ofc besides reports generated on Mondays, Saturdays and Sundays)

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
case trim(to_char(sysdate,'DAY'))
when 'MONDAY' then sysdate-3
when 'SUNDAY' then sysdate-2
else sysdate-1 
end
```

Returns the date of previous business day before now.

Bobby

Comment: Thanks Bobby, This is perfect Oracle SQL statement working fine with regular Oracle Database, but is useless in terms of Oracle OBIEE which do not support this syntax.

Comment: Sorry about that. You need someone who knows OBIEE I guess. We have it but I just see the database part.